# What is an abort trap in python?

Tags: python, argparse, nose

Running my script directly, works as expected.  Testing the main function with nose causes an abort trap.

Function being called:

```
@retry(wait_exponential_multiplier=500, wait_exponential_max=10000, stop_max_attempt_number=7)
def shell_command(**kwargs):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(kwargs['shell_argument'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
    return stdout
```

Test:

```
from nose.tools import raises
@raises(Exception)
def test_shell_fail():
    kwargs = {}
    kwargs['shell_argument'] = ['ls', 'filedoesnotexist']
    myclass.shell_command(**kwargs)
```

I am testing my app with nose, and getting the following error:

```
Fatal Python error: no mem for sys.argv
ValueError: character U+6573552f is not in range [U+0000; U+10ffff]
Abort trap: 6
```

So, what's an abort trap and why don't I get a stack trace?

Baffled.

Comment: A character/value outside of Unicode is being supplied (as read in), as indicated by the ValueError. Not sure if the fatal / trap are a result of, or cause of, however..

Comment: Which OS and specific version of Python (including variation Iron/Jyson/Pypy etc..) are you using? What's the piece of code that you're nose testing - does it have any non-standard library dependencies it uses, etc...?

Comment: OSX.  Python 3.4 picks up my tests and gives the above error.  Tests aren't found in python 2.7.

Comment: Installing nose fixes this issue.  Seems to be a rookie error, however nothing in the output leads me to look at nose.  Having 49 virtualenvs makes it a little tricky to remember what you have installed where ;).